# Damage caused by pigeons who is liable

Tags: residential-lease, small-claims-court

I own a flat in the UK and I have a problem with pigeons living under the the decking of my balcony.

The balcony is within my demised property (as the leasholder), but the drainage pipe that the birds have crawled up is on the outside of the property.

The freeholder is refusing to pay for repairs as they're saying it's within my demised property.

To me this seems a similar situation to damage being caused by a roof leak.

Three separate properties have experienced the problem and bird guards have been installed on the other drainage pipes.

Would i have a case in a small claims court?

Comment: By drainage pipe is it a down-pipe from the building's guttering?

Comment: It allows drainage from the balcony into the building's guttering. So yes.